# How to escape less than sign in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having an issue that I can't seem to solve myself. I have the following code below:

```
var symbol = {
heart: /<3/gm,
};
```

I'm trying to search for the heart text symbol but I it can't find it upon searching text. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: All you have is a regular expression. How are you attempting to *use* it? We need to see more code.

Comment: Are you searching code already printed on screen? If so, it's probably encoded as `&lt;`

Comment: in some browsers, the last comma in your object literal will cause an error.

Comment: @0SX, in that case, I made it into an answer below.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try `&lt;` in place of `<`

Comment: Perfect! THanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it works to me.

```
symbol = { heart: /<3/gm, };
> Object
"hi there <3".match(symbol.heart)
> ["<3"]
```

Perhaps your problem lies elsewhere?

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it. I was just wondering if I had something wrong with that before I moved on.