# XSL unable to parse foor loop

Tags: javascript, xml

i'm using JavaScript for loop inside xsl document as follows:

```
     var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("section");
     for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
            { 

                alert((x[i].getElementsByTagName("SectionId").nodeValue));
                alert((x[i].getElementsByTagName("SectionName").nodeValue));

            }
```

but i don't understand why the following error occurs:

```
Element type "x.length" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"
```

Comment: Escape the <. XSL believes an element is starting there.

Comment: i tried this:  for (i=0;i <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">< x.length;i++) but didn't work

Comment: This is not how you escape characters in javascript. `disable-output-escaping` is used in XSL stylesheets to control what a serializer translates a "<" character _into_.

Answer (score 1):

No need to add the `<xsl:text disable...`. You could try escaping the "<" character with `&lt;`.

This is related: [How to escape less than sign in javascript/jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045745/how-to-escape-less-than-sign-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: i tried &lt; it but javascript refused "Uncaught syntax error unexpected token;"